# Custom Backspace button functionality android for deleting chars onLongPress

Tags: android, keyboard

I'm making a keyboard app in which i use a image of backspace for deleting character entered in edittext (disable default keyboard) normal delete functionality achieved on ClickListener.But if user long Press the button it should delete chars smoothly but not all chars at once.

Comment: use onlongclicklistener

Comment: used it. but it take only once then do not delete the chars.

for (int i = 0; i < stringBuilder.length(); i++) {
                    stringBuilder.setLength(stringBuilder.length() - 1);
                }
                etMyText.setText(stringBuilder.toString());

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try onTouchListener and use particular time for deletion of single char.

you can try like

```
 final Handler handler = new Handler(); 
 Runnable mLongPressed = new Runnable() { 
    public void run() { 
         //remove one char
         handler.postDelayed(this, 200);

    }   
  };

button.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
              switch (event.getAction()) {
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                    //remove on char
                    handler.postDelayed(mLongPressed,  200);
                    break;
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                     handler.removeCallbacks(mLongPressed);

                    break;
    }
                return true;
            }
        });
```

this runnable run() code will be executed with 200 ms delay. And it will be executed when the button is in pressed state.